# onclick= change all input text field background color of the same class in a form

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, forms, getelementsbyclassname

Getting this to work in IE7.
Trying to change background color of input text fields in a form via class.
I understand IE7 does not support getelementsbyClassName so function has to be created. I've tried many examples of getelementsbyClassName function out there but none have worked for me. Hopefully someone can provide a solution for me.

```
function changecolor() {
    //i don't know what to put here
}

<input type="text" class="items">
<input type="text" class="items">
<input type="text" class="items">
<div onclick="changecolor()">Change Color</div>
```

Comment: why not use Jquery......

Comment: @naimshaikh if the user wanted jQuery, he should have tagged it - but he didn't

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Comment: i don't mind using jquery if it helps but I can't seem to get his code to work :/

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick in IE7:

```
function changecolor(c){
  var a,n;
  a=getElementsByTagName('INPUT'); // or a=document.all for all elements in items-class;
  for(n=0;n<a.length;a++){
   if(a[n].className=='items'){
     a[n].style.backgroundColor=c;
   }
   return;
}
```

You can also edit the rule in the `class`, but it is not guaranteed to really change the color, before reflowing the page.

```
function changeColor(c){
    var sSheet,n;
    sSheet=document.styleSheets[0].rules;
    for(n=0;n<sSheet.length;n++){
        if(sSheet[n].selectorText=='.items') sSheet[n].style.backgroundColor=c;
    }
    return;
}
```

You can use the `id` of the `styleSheet` instead of the index in `styleSheets[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use modern functions but need to support ancient browsers, the best solution is to use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

With jQuery what you want to do is super-easy:

```
<input type="text" class="items">
<input type="text" class="items">
<input type="text" class="items">
<div id="changeColor">Change Color</div>

<script>
$('#changeColor').on('click', function() {
     $('input.items').css('backgroundColor', '#0ff');
});
</script>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/kSwv8/